# Java exit code -805306369 returned when moving JavaFx node

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have an JavaFX project, I have an anchorpane in which I have my own component: classBox(extends a vBox) to make this Box movable I use the code below.
The problem I have is that sometimes when run my project and start moving the boxes my program stops responding and then when I close it I get exit code -805306369.
I have no clue why I get this error and why only sometimes and not always. (I use IntelliJ to run my program)

```
public class BoxView extends ClassBox implements InvalidationListener {
private BoxModel model;

public BoxView(BoxModel model) {
    this.model = model;
    model.addListener(this);
    makeDragable();
    heightProperty().addListener((Observable o) -> model.setHeight(getHeight()));
}

@Override
public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
    if (model.getBox() != null){
        setName(model.getBox().getName());
        setAttributes(model.getBox().getAttributes());
        setOperations(model.getBox().getOperations());
        setPrefWidth(model.getBox().getWidth());
        setLayoutX(model.getBox().getCol());
        setLayoutY(model.getBox().getRow());
    }
}

public void makeDragable(){
    final Coordinate cornerDist = new Coordinate();
    this.setOnMouseEntered(mouseEvent -> this.setCursor(Cursor.HAND));
    this.setOnMouseReleased(mouseEvent -> this.setCursor(Cursor.HAND));
    this.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {
        this.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        cornerDist.setX(this.getLayoutX() - mouseEvent.getSceneX());
        cornerDist.setY(this.getLayoutY() - mouseEvent.getSceneY());
    });
    this.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> model.setPos(new Coordinate(mouseEvent.getSceneX() + cornerDist.getX(),
            mouseEvent.getSceneY() + cornerDist.getY())));
}
```

}

Comment: There were similar issues caused by the nvidia driver, do you have the latest driver version?

Comment: I checked for updates and my driver was up to date.

Comment: What's the driver version you have? 378.49 is affected and it's not the latest one. If there is no newer driver for your card, rollback to an older version.

Comment: I am currently using version 381.65 on a 930M

Comment: Then your problem is different.

Comment: Ok, thank you for trying to help me.